# Função default do Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulpfile

Gostaria de fazer as "tasks" abaixo rodarem simultaneamente, como devo proceder?

```js
var gulp = require('gulp')
,clean = require('gulp-clean')
,imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin')
,cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css')
,minify = require('gulp-minify')
,inlinesource = require('gulp-inline-source')
,htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin')
,browserSync = require ('browser-sync');

gulp.task('copy', function(){
 return gulp.src('src/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean',function(){
 return gulp.src('./dist')
        .pipe(clean());
});

exports.buildImg = () => (
    gulp.src('./dist/imagens/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/imagens'))
);

gulp.task('minify-css', () => {
    return gulp.src('./src/css/**/*.css')
      .pipe(cleanCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('minify-js', function(cb) {
    gulp.src(['./src/scripts/**/*.js'])
      .pipe(minify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/scripts'))
      cb();
});

gulp.task('inline', function () {
    return gulp.src('./dist/**/*.html')
        .pipe(inlinesource())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('minify-html', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/*.html')
      .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: Mas porque deveriam rodar simultaneamente? Não é melhor sequencialmente? Ainda mais que parece que alguns dos processos dependem dos anteriores? O que poderia resolver com `gulp.series` ou `runSequence`. Já se for pra rodar simultaneamente (q me parece ser o sentido de paralelamente) usaria o `gulp.parallel`

Comment: Sim Guilherme, acredito que sequencialmente seria o ideal, como devo proceder por favor?

Comment: Esta usando Gulp 3.9 ou Gulp 4.0 (esse é bem novo, eu ainda não migrei meus projetos com gulp pro 4)? Se não souber digita no terminal ou cmd para acessar a pasta do projeto e digita `gulp --version`, pega a versão do "gulp local"

Comment: To usando o 4.0, com o 3.9 tava tudo beleza, quando migrei tive alguns problemas,

Comment: O `gulp.series()` resolve pro 4.0, se for o 3.9 vai ter que instalar o runSequence

Answer (score 0):

Adicione essa linha no final do código para setar todas as *tasks* especificadas como *default*:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('copy', 'clean', 'minify-css', 'minify-js', 'inline', 'minify-html'));
```

Após isso basta digitar *gulp* que por padrão todas as *tasks* serão executadas

Comment: Obrigado Mohamad, vou tentar e lhe dou um retorno.